# Find the most recent date from a nested array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a `Multilevel Array` (*See array structure picture below*) and I need to get the sub-nested array with the higher `date value`.

I was wondering if there is a straight forward way to sort sub-nested arrays by `date value` or get the highest `date value`?

**Array Map**
[image]

Comment: I'd probably start by looking at [usort](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that, [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function will be useful:

```
usort($rgData, function($rgX, $rgY)
{
   $x = strtotime($rgX['date']);
   $y = strtotime($rgY['date']);
   return $x<$y?-1:$x!=$y;
});
//var_dump($rgData);
```

if you want to get highest value, then it will be `['date']` key of last element after doing the sort above.

Edit: if you're sure that format will be exactly same as on picture always, you can use direct string comparison via `strcmp` (that would be probably faster)

Comment: Is converting them from a string to an integer really necessary? The string cmp function would suffice for ordering them too, would it not?

Comment: @crush because if you'll compare dates as strings you'll get wrong result in case when `$x < $y` as date, but `$x > $y` as string.

Comment: That's not true when the dates use leading 0's in the format provided.

Comment: Since I'm not sure about format, I've used `strtotime` (may be there will be even such things as 'Jan'..'Dec' for monthes)

Comment: The author posted the format above. It's a very standard `DateTime` format most likely delivered from a `DateTime` field in his database.

Comment: I've tested both and it seems that `strtotime` is faster ? `strtotime 0.000105` vs string comparison `1.5E-5` ( I think this number is bigger but no idea what the E-5 means)

Comment: @JonathanThurft I just tested it myself, and found that [strtotime was much, much slower](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/caad13d8cab82bbec235034ef21156abe314c942).

Comment: @JonathanThurft You don't know what `E-5` means? It's scientific notation. It means 1.5 x 10^-5, which comes out out to `.000015` which is much less than `.000105`. So even your own test shows that `strcmp` is much faster, by an order of `10x`.

Comment: The reason `strcmp` is faster lies in the string parsing that happens in `strtotime` which converts the string date into an integer. If this step didn't exist, then obviously comparing integers instead of strings would be much faster. Unfortunately, you have to perform 2 `strtotime` conversions on each object.

Comment: Please add an example for `strcmp`: `usort($rgData, function($rgX, $rgY) { return strcmp($rgX['date'], $rgY['date']); });`

Comment: @crush already did that, thank you (hope format will always be the same)

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
$input = array(
    array('date' => '2013-09-11 13:08:40 +0000'),
    array('date' => '2013-09-11 13:09:17 +0000'));

usort($input, function(array $a, array $b) {
    $aTimestamp = strtotime($a['date']);
    $bTimestamp = strtotime($b['date']);

    if($aTimestamp == $bTimestamp) return 0;
    return $aTimestamp < $bTimestamp;
});

print_r($input); //$input[0] has the latest date value
```